# How would I physically implement an optical parametric amplifier in the lab?

Tags: quantum-optics

This might seem like a silly question, but I want to learn more about optical parametric amplifiers (OPAs), specifically for use in quantum optic exerpiments, and it is unclear to me whether one goes out and purchases these amplifiers, or if one makes their own. From the theory I have read, it appears as though an OPA is simply a nonlinear crystal that one inputs two beams into.  (In contrast to, for example, and SPDC experiment where only one beam is shined into the crystal and the output is two beams).

So I guess my question is, if I wanted to have an OPA in my experiment, would it be as simple as getting a $\chi^{(2)}$ crystal, and shining two beams through it? (After satisfying the phase matching conditions of course).

Comment: There are commercial OPAs, and a lot of groups build theirs in-house; it depends on your budget and on what you want to do. This is a very broad field, and there's a lot of literature on the topic. Have you actually got a lab to implement this in, or is this more of an idle wandering? Keep in mind that things are only ever simple in theory.

Comment: I've also removed your last subquestion as it's already broad enough as it is; you should ask that one separately.

Comment: Right now I am doing some preliminary research for a lab which I work in.  We are going outside our area of expertise to experiment a little in the field of quantum optics. I do not think I am allowed to say much about what exactly we want to do, but one thing for sure is, our budget is limited to something along the lines of 25K in equipment.  So ideally, if it is possible to build an effective OPA rather than buy one, that is what we want to do.